Google Scholar citations in .tex
I would like that every time I compile a LaTex document it automatically pulls up the number of my Google Scholar citations. For example:
I have 51 citations. 

The "51" should pull up automatically. How can I do that? I understand a script might pull things up from the internet and then tex could read up that script. I'd like it done all automatically.
This is a very natural desirability for any academic who publishes.
The follow-up question is doing the same on Web of Science or Scopus etc.

Generally there is no features for LaTeX to automatically go online to get data as that would be very iffy security wise. I would rather make a programme, in, say, python, that gets the data and places it into a file on disk that LaTeX can then use.

can someone integrate this: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/retrieve-google-scholar-results

Since a tool from your [Softwarerecs.SE] link already exists, you can most likely use the proposed duplicate (and/or other questions linked from there) to get the output of that tool into your LaTeX document.

@Marijn my question still requires an integration - it is not covered by what you sent. Could you be explicit?

@bissi as mentioned in the answer to the linked question, adding \input|"python scholar.py --txt-globals --author 'albert einstein' | grep '\[G\]' | grep Results" in your LaTeX code would add the output of the Python script to your document. That is the simplest version, the answer to the linked question expands on this by showing how to extract parts of the output if you are not happy with the raw output (which in this case could also be done by modifying the Python script itself of course).

@Marijn could you post a complete answer? This is a general question which any academic who publishes and uses LaTex would find useful.

@bissi there is no need for a new answer here, the duplicate provides the necessary information. The idea of duplicate closure is to keep everything in one place, and to link to that place when new questions are asked that are also answered (with minimal modifications) by the original question.
